# How could we make rviz subscribe to a topic of arm_navigation_msgs::DisplayTrajectory msgs?

Tags: ros, motion-planning, rviz, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

How could we make rviz subscribe to a topic of arm_navigation_msgs::DisplayTrajectory ?

I am using fuerte.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33880/how-could-we-make-rviz-subscribe-to-a-topic-of-arm_navigation_msgs::displaytrajectory-msgs?/) by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2012-05-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to use the "Planning" display ("Add" -> "New Display" -> "Motion Planning" -> "Planning"). The description says it takes `motion_planning_msgs::KinematicPath`, but that's not true any more; it really takes `arm_navigation_msgs::DisplayTrajectory` messages´. I filed a [ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5443) on that.

(Update: the "Planning" display is loaded via the motion planning RViz plugin, so you need to resolve your [other problem](http://answers.ros.org/question/33864/failed-to-load-motion_planning_rviz_pluginso) first.)

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on 2012-05-15**:
Thanks Martin.